# How to add rows and values for given column?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have the following DataFrame right now, with the following value:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = sparkSession.read().text(pathFile);
+-------+--------+
| VALUE |  TIME  |
+-------+--------+
| 5000  |        |
+-------+--------+
```

where TIME doesn't have a value (or is null). How can I add a value to the TIME column? I will later on my program be adding more rows as well, and I will need to add/append values for both the VALUE and TIME columns. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I add a value to the TIME column?

and

> TIME doesn't have a value (or is null)

leads me to believe that you may want to explore [na](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@na:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions) operator.

> **na: DataFrameNaFunctions** Returns a DataFrameNaFunctions for working with missing data.

that in turn gives you the way to [fill](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@fill(value:String,cols:Array[String]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) missing values.

> **fill(value: String, cols: Array[String]): DataFrame** Returns a new DataFrame that replaces null values in specified string columns. If a specified column is not a string column, it is ignored.

If you just want to replace you should use [withColumn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) operator.

> **withColumn(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame** Returns a new Dataset by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.

As the value for `col` you could use [lit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lit(literal:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

> **lit(literal: Any): Column** Creates a Column of literal value.

The other requirement was...

> be adding more rows as well

That's [union](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@union(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) operator.

> **union(other: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T]** Returns a new Dataset containing union of rows in this Dataset and another Dataset. This is equivalent to UNION ALL in SQL.

Comment: I swear to God I looked through Spark's documentation yesterday for about 30 minutes and I couldn't find any of this functions. I might as well get my eyes checked. Thank you very much @Jacek. If I have a problem with this functions, would you mind helping me go around them?

Comment: _"If I have a problem with this functions, would you mind helping me go around them?"_ Sure! Not only me but the whole Spark community. It's quite active on StackOverflow. If my answer helped, please approve as the answer for future readers. Appreciated!